# Ошибка "Failed to execute script gh" при компиляции приложение на tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Я знаю, что этот вопрос уже задавался на форуме, но подходящего решения я не нашел, так же в отличии от остальных, спрашивающих о проблеме у меня не просто вылетает ошибка при запуска exe, а только у всех кому я кидаю этот файл. Это очень странно: у меня что exe одним файлом, что exe созданный в директории запускается без каких либо проблем, но стоит его скинуть куда то на другой компьютер через облачный сервер, или флешку, или почтой, то резко вылетает ошибка "Failed to execute script gh". [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вдруг поможет код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import math
import math as m
import random

#Начало блока окна
root = Tk()
root.geometry('960x540')
root.title("ReacPicker v1.1")
root.iconbitmap(r'D:\python\charm\учуся\venv\gg\ReacPicker v1.0\4.ico')
#Конец блока окна

#Начало блока переменных
colors = ['red','orange','green','pink', 'lavender', 'cyan']
instr = "Жми играть и полетел тыкать по кружочкам! Один кружочек - 10 очков."
zach = "Ну тут можно потренировать точность своих нажатий, это самая-самая сырая версия - строк в 150." \
       " В последующих версиях планирую добавить возможность редактировать сенсу под разные игры. vk.com/dipperok." \
       " За выходом версий и моих программ можно следить тут: https://yadi.sk/d/uT07AULENBWuIg "

sc = 0
bestScore = 0
timer_running = False  # запущен ли таймер
default_seconds = 60  # изначальное положение(только секунды указывать)
timer_seconds = default_seconds  # текущее положение таймера, сек
radius = 13
#Конец блока переменных

#Начало блока функций
   #Начало Таймера
def timer_start_pause():
    global timer_running
    timer_running = not timer_running  # работа или пауза
    if timer_running:  # работа
        timer_tick()
def timer_reset():
    global timer_running, timer_seconds
    timer_running = False  # стоп
    timer_seconds = default_seconds  # изначальное положение
    show_timer()
def timer_tick():
    global timer_seconds
    if timer_running and timer_seconds:
        label.after(1000, timer_tick)  # перезапустить через 1 сек
        # уменьшить таймер
        timer_seconds -= 1
        show_timer()
def show_timer():
    '''отобразить таймер'''
    m = timer_seconds//60
    s = timer_seconds-m*60
    label['text'] = '%02d:%02d' % (m, s)
    if m == 0:
        if s == 0:
            Win()
   #Конец Таймера

def Instruct():
    messagebox.showinfo("Справка", instr)
def Zachem():
    messagebox.showinfo("Справка", zach)
def Score():
    global sc
    sc += 10
    scoreLB.config(text = "Счет: " + str(sc))
    BestScore()
def BestScore():
    global bestScore, sc, fileW
    if sc > bestScore:
        bestScore = sc
        labelBS.config(text = "лучший: " + str(bestScore))
        fileW = open('gh.txt', 'w')
        fileW.write(str(bestScore))
        fileW.close()
def Start():
    global sc
    timer_reset()
    sc -= 10
    Krujki()
    buttonPlay['state'] = 'disabled'
    show_timer()
    timer_start_pause()
    labelWIN.config(text='', bg="white")
    labelLOSE.config(text = '', bg = "white")
def Krujki():
    global a,b,r, bestScore
    holst.delete(ALL)
    a = random.randint(5, 640)
    b = random.randint(5, 480)
    r = radius
    holst.create_oval(a-r,b-r,a+r,b+r,fill = random.choice(colors), width=1, tag="circle")
    root.after(100)
    Score()
def click(event):
    global x, y, l
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    l = m.sqrt(pow((a - x), 2) + pow((b - y), 2))
    if l > r:
        Lose()
    else:
        Krujki()
        print("Попал")
def Win():
    global sc, bestScore
    holst.delete('circle')
    buttonPlay['state'] = 'active'
    print("а ты не плох твой результат: " + str(sc))
    labelWIN.config(text = 'Твой результат: ' + str(sc), bg="white", fg="#EDA7AC", font = ("Ubuntu", 35))
    timer_reset()
def Lose():
    global sc, bestScore
    holst.delete('circle')
    print("лох")
    buttonPlay['state'] = 'active'
    labelLOSE.config(text = 'Ну ты и лох, попробуй еще, счет: ' + str(sc), bg="white", fg="#EDA7AC", font = ("Ubuntu", 23))
    timer_reset()
    sc = 0
def Minute1():
    global default_seconds
    default_seconds = 60
def Minute2():
    global default_seconds
    default_seconds = 120
def Minute30():
    global default_seconds
    default_seconds = 30
def Minute10():
    global default_seconds
    default_seconds = 10
#Конец блока функций


#Начало блока меню
menu1 = Menu(root)
root.configure(menu=menu1)
menu1.add_command(label = "Инструкция", command=Instruct)
menu1.add_command(label = "О программе", command=Zachem)
#Конец блока меню

#Начало блока объектов
holst = Canvas(root, width=670, height=500, bg='white')
label1 = Label(root, text = 'ReacPicker v1.1', font = ("Ubuntu", 14))
label = Label(root, font = ("Ubuntu", 22))
labelWIN = Label(root, text = '', bg="white")
labelLOSE = Label(root, text = '', fg="white")
labelBS = Label(root, text = "лучший: ", font = ("Ubuntu", 16))
buttonPlay = Button(root, text = 'Играть', font = 30,height=5, width=25,  command=Start)
scoreLB = Label(root, text = "Счет: " + str(sc), font = ("Ubuntu", 22))
button1 = Button(root, text = '1 мин.', font = 30,height=4, width=6,  command=Minute1)
button2 = Button(root, text = '2 мин.', font = 30,height=4, width=6,  command=Minute2)
button30 = Button(root, text = '30 сек', font = 30,height=4, width=6,  command=Minute30)
button10 = Button(root, text = '10 сек', font = 30,height=4, width=6,  command=Minute10)
#конец блока объектов

#Начало блока размещения
holst.place(x= 10, y= 10)
label.place(x= 700,y= 400 )
label1.place(x= 700, y= 20)
labelLOSE.place(x= 50,y= 450)
labelWIN.place(x= 50,y= 50)
labelBS.place(x= 700, y= 85)
buttonPlay.place(x= 700, y= 130)
scoreLB.place(x= 700,y= 450)
button1.place(x= 830, y= 235)
button2.place(x= 895, y= 235)
button30.place(x= 765, y= 235)
button10.place(x= 700, y= 235)
#Конец блока размещения
holst.bind('<Button-1>', click)
fileW = open('gh.txt', 'r')
bestScore = int(fileW.read())
labelBS.config(text = "лучший: " + str(bestScore))
root.mainloop()
```

Пробовал компилировать через консоль командой: pyinstaller -y -w -i "D:\python\charm\учуся\venv\gg\ReacPicker v1.0\4.ico" --add-data "D:/python/charm/учуся/venv/gg/ReacPicker v1.0/gh.txt";"."

Так же через auto-py-to-exe 2.6.6:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для `pyinstaller` я бы еще добавил флаг `-F`

Comment: @finally это компилирует в один файл, разницы никакой пробовал множество раз, просто на скринах вариация компиляции в директорию, а так что там, что там вылетает на других компьютерах "Failed to execute script gh", что с флагом -F.

Comment: пробовали с другим кодом? если дело не в нем, то у ваших знакомых видимо все неоч..

Comment: Такая же проблема у всех моих программ и даже в несколько десятков строк, проблема не в друзьях, пробывал запускать у себя дома с двух других компьютеров, в кабинете информатики ,у двух друзей, что с едином файлом(-F), что с директорией файлов одна и та же ошибка

Comment: я вам так скажу, у меня такое было, когда у меня были необычные конструкции в коде, типо всякие `try: except`, но в таком случае программа не запускалась и у меня.. а если у вас все норм, но у других нет, даже не знаю в чем может быть дело, попробуйте на всякий переустановить

Comment: @finally Переустановил, теперь она не работает с флагом ф и у меня, а с директорией завтра проверю опять на других пк

Comment: Сначала переустановил инсталлер, потом питон, пробовал установить 3.6, тоже не помогло, опять установил 3.7 только тепер ьвообще никак не запускается, даже у меня.

Comment: столько мистики в одном моменте, позже попробую с вашим кодом, если у меня все выйдет - вы что то делаете не так..

Comment: С чего вы взяли что на других компьютерах есть такой путь ? "D:\python\charm\учуся\venv\gg\ReacPicker v1.0\4.ico" для начала уберите кирилицу в пути      потом закоментируйте  эту строку root.iconbitmap(r'D:\python\charm\учуся\venv\gg\ReacPicker v1.0\4.ico')  и попробуйте заново

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Пишу ответ сюда, что бы вопрос был, как помечен, как получивший ответ)
Спасибо Александру. Проблема очевидна, но я почему-то не догадаться, что pyinstaller не будет автоматом в ткинтере определять какие файлы задействуются и заносить их и тд.
Короче, решение проблемы с крашем: не должно быть путей не существующих на других компьютерах, пути должны быть на английском. Лично я просто создал директорей, а не единым файлом и добавил иконку как файл туда через pyinsyaller команда добавляющая файл: `"D:/python/myaw/ReacPicker v1.0/4.ico" --add-data` и путь указал на просто как "4.ico"